# Disable chunked transfer flowjs

Tags: angularjs, flow-js, ng-flow

I am using ng-flow directive for uploading files to server. Is there a way i can use normal upload instead of chunked upload that is used in ng-flow module?

Comment: what do you mean with 'normal upload'?

Comment: I mean just one request because i want to upload xml files that should be parsed and saved in database not in file on server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set property **testChunks:** **false** to config flow, for example:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['flow']).
    config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
        flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
            target: '/upload',
            permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
            maxChunkRetries: 1,
            chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
            simultaneousUploads: 4,
            testChunks: true
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: `testChunks` does not enable or disable chunked uploads. What it does is disable the check to see which chunks were uploaded before. This way, the file upload can be resumed even after a browser crash/restart.

Answer (score 7):

You could set the `chunkSize` to a very high value (e.g., 9007199254740992, javascripts largest integer value).

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['flow']).
config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
    flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
        target: '/upload',
        permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
        chunkSize: 9007199254740992,
        maxChunkRetries: 1,
        chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
        testChunks: false
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, both of the 2 methods given doesn't work. When looking at the [doc](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) I have found a configuration attribute called `testMethod` setting this to null solved the problem for me :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['flow']).
  config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
    flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
      testMethod: null
  };
}]);
```